# Huawei P7 connect to wi-fi but doesn't open any website

Tags: huawei

Hello my Huawei P7 connects to wi-fi but doesn't open any website in any browser! I also can't check my emails and any other application can't connect to internet.
I've also Factory reset my phone.

Comment: Well, that's weird did you checked your Wi-Fi connection if its working or not ?? Sometimes this happens because the router needs resetting, can try restarting the router and see if that help you ! At first I was thinking that the problem might be somewhere because of using some proxy app over your device but as you have factory reset it means, it also gets wiped out ! So, I guess try restarting the router will be a best option.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but the Wi-Fi router isn't mine! I mean it's my collage free Wi-Fi. I hope you understand what I mean; I can't access the router. my classmates are using this Wi-Fi without any problem

Comment: Well, in that case try heading over to the settings>wireless and Network>Look for your college wifi>Tap and hold over it until a popup shows up>tap Forget Network,once done switch the Wi-Fi off and then again ON, then again try connecting to the Wifi network and see if this time things work out for you !

Comment: In the place Peter just described, how is the network presented: "saved", "connected", or something else? It might well be that specific WiFi is locking you out (MAC-filter). Can you connect to other WiFi networks?

Comment: Today I brought my phone to it's Grantee and they flashed it and then they connected to their WiFi network; but when I came back to the Collage I still wasn't able to connect! again the same problem. so what should I do now?